# Simple $_GET question

Tags: php, jquery

Hey, i am currently creating a pagination script using php and jquery and for some reason can't display the $_GET that im trying to grab.

There is no form, but looking at the firebug console I get a url like this:

```
pagination.php?id=category
```

Just wondering how I can get that 'category' and just echo it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`echo $_GET['id'];`

Just in case that "category" is a URL, try to encode it, otherwise it will not populate correctly; and finally, don't use variables over 100 characters in length.

Answer (score 4):

doesn't `$_GET['id']` do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

also, be sure to sanitize user input before doing anything with it.